# Loop through ICollections

Tags: c#, .net

I have collection object

```
public ICollection<DataOutput> DataCollection { get; set; }
```

When I try to loop through the collection

```
for(DataOutput item in data.DataCollection)
{

}
```

it says only assignment call increment decrement can be used as a statement under `data.DataCollection`. Can anybody point out where I am doing the mistake please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# keyword you think you are using is called [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
foreach (DataOutput item in data.DataCollection)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe I read `foreach` where he said `for`. Nice catch!

Comment: Nice catch. I was wasting may whole day to figure out what's wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `foreach(DataOutput item in data.DataCollection)`.